# repeating a Partial View does not work

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an index page, where I have a link to call a partial view.  The code is as follows :-

```
@model MvcCommons.ViewModels.CompositeViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.jtruncate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    $('.text').jTruncate({
        length: 100,
        minTrail: 0,
        moreText: "",
        lessText: "Read Less",
        //ellipsisText: " (Click below to continue reading)"
    });
});
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myTable01').fixedHeaderTable({
    footer: false,
    cloneHeadToFoot: false,
    altClass: 'odd',
    autoShow: false
});


</script>
<table class="fancyTable" id="myTable01" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleTitle)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleDate)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleText)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleSource)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.Category.CategoryTitle)
    </th>
    <th>
        Images
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.ArticleViewModel.ArticleList)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArticleTitle)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArticleDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="text">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArticleText)
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArticleSource)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.CategoryTitle)
    </td>
    <td>
        @if (Model.ImageViewModel.ImageCount(item.ArticleID, Model.ImageViewModel.PageID) > 0)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.PageViewModel.Page.PageTitle, new { id = "PageTitle" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.PageViewModel.Page.PageAction, new { id = "PageAction" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.ArticleID, new { id = "ItemID" })
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/ViewImages.cshtml", Model)
        }
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ArticleID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ArticleID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ArticleID })
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>

<p>
     @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")


</p>
```

The ViewImages.cshtml page is as follows :-

```
@model MvcCommons.ViewModels.CompositeViewModel

@{

ViewBag.Title = "Modal image uploader";
}


<script type="text/javascript">
var pageTitle = $('#PageTitle').val();
var pageAction = $('#PageAction').val();
var id = $('#ItemID').val();

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.modal_block').click(function (e) {
        $('#tn_select').empty();
        $('.modal_part').hide();
    });
    $('#modal_view_link').click(function (e) {
        $('.modal_part').show();
        var context = $('#tn_view_select').load('/Upload/Index?Page=' + pageTitle + '&Action=' + pageAction + '&id=' + id, function () {
            initSelect(context);
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

});

</script>

<div class="modal_block modal_part"></div>
<div class="modal_dialog modal_part" id="tn_view_select"></div>



<p>

<a href="#" id="modal_view_link" >Click here to view the images</a>
</p>
```

My Problem is that since the Index is a repeater, I need to distinguish between these partial views, since at the moment, only the first link will work (in the index page).

What I think needs to be done is that in the ViewImages.cshtml, this part of the code:-

```
<a href="#" id="modal_view_link" >Click here to view the images</a>
```

the id needs to be unique for all the links.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Thanks for your help and time

---

UPDATE - Move everything in 1 page, Index.cshtml, however still not working properly

```
@model MvcCommons.ViewModels.CompositeViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.jtruncate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var pageTitle = $('#PageTitle').val();
var pageAction = $('#PageAction').val();
var id = $('#ItemID').val();

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.modal_block').click(function (e) {
        $('#tn_select').empty();
        $('.modal_part').hide();
    });
    $('#modal_view_link').click(function (e) {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $('.modal_part').show();
        var context = $('#tn_view_select').load('/Upload/Index?Page=' + pageTitle + '&Action=' + pageAction + '&id=' + id, function () {
            initSelect(context);
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

    $('#myTable01').fixedHeaderTable({
        footer: false,
        cloneHeadToFoot: false,
        altClass: 'odd',
        autoShow: false
    });

});

</script>


<table class="fancyTable" id="myTable01" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleTitle)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleDate)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleText)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleSource)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.Category.CategoryTitle)
    </th>
    <th>
        Images
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@{var i = 0;}

@foreach (var item in Model.ArticleViewModel.ArticleList)
{
i++;
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArticleTitle)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArticleDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="text">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArticleText)
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArticleSource)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.CategoryTitle)
    </td>
    <td>
        @if (Model.ImageViewModel.ImageCount(item.ArticleID, Model.ImageViewModel.PageID) > 0)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.PageViewModel.Page.PageTitle, new { id = "PageTitle" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.PageViewModel.Page.PageAction, new { id = "PageAction" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.ArticleID, new { id = "ItemID" })
            <a href="#" class="modal_view_link" data-id="@(i)">Click here to view the images</a>
        }
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ArticleID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ArticleID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ArticleID })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to render that `<script>` stuff in `ViewImages.cshtml` for every iteration of `Model.ArticleViewModel.ArticleList` that satisfies your `ImageCount` condition?

I'd have the `<script>` stuff rendered to the page once (ie: outside of the `foreach`) and the `<a ..>` pulled out of the partial view and put directly within the `foreach`.

You can then switch the foreach into;

```
@{var articleList = Model.ArticleViewModel.ArticleList; }
@for(int i = 0;i< articleList.Count; i++) {
     ...
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => articleList[i], new { id = "ItemID" })
     <a href="#" class="modal_view_link" data-id="@(i)">Click here to view the images</a>
     ...
}
```

Then update the jQuery to something like;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ...
    $('.modal_view_link').click(function (e) {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var context = $('#tn_view_select').load('/Upload/Index?Page=' + pageTitle + '&Action=' + pageAction + '&id=' + id, function () {
            initSelect(context);
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Stafford the reason why I wanted the <script> inside the ViewImages.cshtml, because I am going to include this in more pages, and so I did not want to repeat the <script> every time on every page

Comment: I can also see a problem with this approach, since the <script> will not have different instances of "modal_view_link" but only 1 instance.

Comment: Hi Stafford ArticleList is an IEnumerable<> so I cannot do the for int.  I left everything as is and tried to put this link instead of the partial view call ...... <a href="#" class="modal_view_link" data-id="@item.ArticleID">Click here to view the images</a> but the data-id did not work

Comment: There are ways around the IEnumberable, you make the Model expose something that can be indexed, or you can add `int=0;` before the `foreach` and add the `i++;` within the `foreach`

Comment: As for the jquery, you want to use your selectors to apply events (ie; click event) to all your elements (regardless of id), but when executing query for the ids and act appropriately.

Comment: Stafford I updated my question with your suggestion, however still not working, when I click nothing happens